# Background Image not showing on gitHub pages

Tags: html, css, image, github

I have recently got into web development and I have run into issues with images not being displayed after pushing them to Github pages. I have browsed through countless posts on changing the directory, using quotation marks, and even special characters like so ../ . I am hoping someone can just explain to me what the hell is going on within my code. Below is a snippet of the CSS I had written, it worked perfectly fine on the local host.

```css
.background-image{
    background-image: url('/index.html/back/banner2.jpg');
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
}
```

[Below is an image of my directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwvs1.png)

Comment: Could you link the repository of the GitHub? Also, are you sure that the path starts with `index.html` and isn't just `/back/banner2.jpg`.

Comment: https://github.com/Shvang42/AladdinsContracting

Comment: And yes the path starts with index.html

Comment: Shouldn't the path be `../back/banner2.jpg`?

Comment: I will try it now

Comment: Thank you this worked you are a live saver!

Comment: You tried with root path (where index.html file is placed), and that is inside index.html-directory, therefore it didn't work properly. Here are a quick guide to file paths: https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that background image is this directory?
Are you tried to put a dot before /index.html/back/banner2.jpg?
Can we please see your repository on GitHub Pages?

Comment: github.com/Shvang42/AladdinsContracting

Comment: Everything seems to be inside the respository, github should be displaying the image. I have tried the ./ and the ../ method.

Comment: The dot method worked thank you, I just had to remove index.html with ..